# Android: Programmatically getting layout params and copying views

Tags: android, xml

Say you have a TextView that you made in an xml file. I am wondering if it is possible to copy this view's Layout Parameters programmatically instead of having to programmatically write them all out again. Or if you could just create a new TextView and make it the same as the original one and then attach it to a new view that will be added.

I tried the latter and ran into the error that said:

```
08-09 22:04:55.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

But this error would persist even after I had tried removing them from the initial view. Any ideas? Or is this just completely unfeasible and dumb.

Comment: What do you mean "make it the same as the original one"?  Did you do something like textView2 = textView1?

Comment: I meant for it to have all the same attributes: such as its gravity, margins and text size. What @Collin proposed works perfectly for what I was imagining.

Comment: Sure, but you said you tried it.  The exception you got suggests that you did indeed try to add the same textview and I wondered if you understood why `TextView textView2 = new TextView();textView2 = textVew1;myLayout.add(textView2);` will fail?

Comment: Oh sorry I now understand you, and I do not know. I guess my assumptions for why it didn't work was because the original views were set statically and could not be removed even if it were called to be. Is this by any means correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always inflate a new `View` from the same xml.  `Adapter` classes do this all the time, for example in `ListView`s the adapter will inflate all if it's rows from the same xml resource.

Comment: Thank you, never even thought about approaching it this way. This works great.

Comment: I'm glad!  If it worked for you, you can mark it as accepted so that future readers know what works.  And if you have any follow up questions I'm here to help.

Comment: Even though the following answer works as well, I selected this as the accepted answer because it most simplified my situation. Now I am curious on how to handle events for the new views. When you use an `Adapter` you are able to manage clicks on each "item" that is added as a whole. But say the view I inflate contains `EditText` views how would I be able to handle these. My thoughts are to create a custom `Adapter` but I feel there may be a more simple way. Just looking for some thoughts on this.

Comment: There is a listener class for this purpose exactly.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can get layout params for that specular TextView with;

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView) findViewById(<your-TextView's-id>);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layPar=myTextView.getLayoutParams();
```

and you can copy another one from this and add it to new view like this;

```
newView.addView(newTextView);
```

Comment: I get NullException, cause there probalby is no LayoutParams in myTextView. In my XML yet I have set many of those.

Comment: @TomeeNS make sure you call getLayoutParams() after the view got attached to its parent.